# How should I give the repo url in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, bitbucket

I am using capistrano for deployment of my rails application. In my config/deploy.rb file how should I give the repo url.

I am following this tutorial:
https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

Instead of
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:excid3/myapp.git'

what should be given there if I am using bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bitbucket, you would use:

```
git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git
or
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

See "[Use the SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)"

Note: [the comments of the tutorial mentioned in the question](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04#comment-1554568108) add:

> Your local key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` will be tried against the server's `/home/deploy/authorized_keys` file.
>   Capistrano won't allow password authentication, so you must make sure you ran the `ssh-copy-id` to add your pub key to the server deploy user's `authorized_keys` file.